# Killing ASP.NET threads

Tags: asp.net, shared-hosting, kill

In my ASP.NET application, I have a script that I periodically automatically call to update the database. Due to a bug in this code, several invocation of it entered an infinite loop.

I am on a shared hosting, so I can't just restart IIS. I have tried “stopping” the website from the hosting's management website, but it had no effect.

Since they are running for seveal hours now, I assume there is no timeout configured. So, I would like to kill those “processes” (I assume it's actually just threads), is there a way to do that without contacting my hosting company?

Comment: At this point I think the only way is to restart the App Pool.  If you have access to this.

Comment: You mention they are still running so I assume that you know this because they are still making database calls?  It depends on the code, but you may able to cause an exception by killing their connection to the database resulting in the threads terminating? (Entirely depends on your exception handling and the way connections are maintained of course).  If the threads open and close connections too quickly to terminate them, try locking the table they require and force a Sql Timeout that way? i.e. BEGIN TRAN, SELECT * FROM TableThreadsAreUsing (Bearing in mind that will lock everyone out)

Comment: infinite loop? No, the hosting company will ban you for hogging cpu time

Comment: @Dee, it's an infinite loop, but not CPU-intensive.

Comment: @Smudge, I know they are still running, because they write to a (file-based) log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was logging some information from the threads I wanted to kill to a file. The code is able to create the file if it doesn't exists, but the same does not apply, to the folder it's in.

So I temporarily renamed the folder with the log and the threads seem to have stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the web.config will stop your application. Assuming you can access the files of the website.

Comment: Changing the web.config will start a new AppDomain.  The previous AppDomain, AFAIK, will persist in the background until execution is complete (done this way to allow deployments without disturbing live websites, the previous AppDomain should live long enough to service existing requests).  Will the old AppDomain consider the long running tasks reason enough to continue the previous AppDomain?

Comment: Doing this seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stopping the application pool for the website?

Comment: Depends on the IIS Version.. http://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-a-32-bit-application-pool-in-iis7-dedicatedvps.aspx (just show where the application pools are)